# How to use JTAG and pogo and USB?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, msp430, jtag

I need to use pogo connectors/pads that will be routed to MSP430 microcontroller. These pogo pads will be routed in a way that allows for JTAG 4-wire programming to program the microcontroller. Is there a way/cable to connect from your PC (like USB) to JTAG that uses pogo connectors? I need to incorporate these three elements: POGO, JTAG, and USB.

Comment: too broad, you would need to make or buy a board that matches the mcu board some way to mechanically hold them together with the pins in the right place not shorting across pads or other.  Then on the other end you need something to wiggle the jtag signals and match the protocol.  All of this is very doable, but there is no way for us to know if this is an off the shelf purchase recommendation, or if you need to build a board/cable or somewhere in between.

Comment: Yes, this is all done on a PCB I'm making. So anything is fair game in terms of designing the board. I just don't know how to make the correlation between these three (USB, POGO, JTAG). Maybe a better question would be, how to program a MSP430 using POGO pads/connectors and a USB?

Comment: POGO pins/pads are essentially just part of the connection a separate conversation.   The usb to jtag is your first problem how are you solving that, from there then you can design your whatever to debug interface solution.

Comment: Why does it have to be pogo pins? Can you just put a tiny connector on your PCB for the JTAG? Some of the MSP430 dev boards used a 0.05" right-angle header for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

The typical setup is:

- **JTAG adapter**: connected to your PC via USB
- **Pogo adapter cable**: connected to your JTAG adapter (e.g. using a JTAG connector)
- The PCB has 4 **pads or holes** in a row that the pogo pins can be pressed against

Well-know adapter cables are from [Tag-Connect](https://www.tag-connect.com/). In addition to the pogo pins, they have alignment pins. They don't have a 4 pin version though.

[image]

Less expensive offers exist in China, e.g. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000317819667.html. At least the cable would be usable.

[image]